# how to add jquery tabcontrol in jquery dialog that open from other jquery dialog have a tab control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jquery dialog form that contains a jquery tabcontrol.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var dialog = $("#CreateForm").parentsUntil(".ui-dialog");
        dialog[0]["validateFilter"] = { ignore: "" };
        dialog[0]["formInvalidCallback"] = function () {
            $("#PersonTab").tabs("select", $("form .input-validation-error").closest(".ui-tabs-panel").get(0).id);
        };
        $(dialog).parent().find(".ui-dialog-content").addClass("dialog-content-nopadding");
        dialog.find("#PersonTab").tabs({
            "show": function (event, ui) {
                if (!$(dialog)[0].dragged)
                    dialog.dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table.display', ui.panel).dataTable();
                if (oTable.length > 0) {
                    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset style="min-width:550px">
        <div>
            <div id="PersonTab" class="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#General-tab">@Html.StaticText("Person_General_Tab")</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#PrefermentJob-tab">@Html.StaticText("JobTPerson_PrefermentJob_Tab")</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#JustifyJob-tab">@Html.StaticText("JobTPerson_JustifyJob_Tab")</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="General-tab">
                    @Html.Partial("Details")
                </div>


                <div id="PrefermentJob-tab">
                    @Html.Partial("PrefermentJobList")

                </div>
                <div id="JustifyJob-tab">
                    @Html.Partial("JustifyJobList")

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

[This is output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvBgd.jpg)

this tabcontrol opens another jquery dialog. and new jquery dialog has jquery tabcontrol itself.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dialog = $("#CreateJobForm").parentsUntil(".ui-dialog");
        dialog[0]["validateFilter"] = { ignore: "" };
        dialog[0]["formInvalidCallback"] = function () {
            $("#JobTab").tabs("select", $("form .input-validation-error").closest(".ui-tabs-panel").get(0).id);
        };
        $(dialog).parent().find(".ui-dialog-content").addClass("dialog-content-nopadding");
        dialog.find("#JobTab").tabs({
            "show": function (event, ui) {
                if (!$(dialog)[0].dragged)
                    dialog.dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table.display', ui.panel).dataTable();
                if (oTable.length > 0) {
                    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateJobForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset style="min-width:550px">
        <div>
            <div id="JobTab" class="tabs">
                <ul >
                    <li><a href="#General-tab">@Html.StaticText("Job_General_Tab")</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Education-tab">@Html.StaticText("Job_JobEducationList_Tab")</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Indicator-tab">@Html.StaticText("Job_JobIndicatorList_Tab")</a></li>

                </ul>
                <div id="General-tab">
                    @Html.Partial("DetailsJob")
                </div>
                <div id="Education-tab">
                    @Html.Partial("JobEducationList")

                </div>
                <div id="Indicator-tab">
                    @Html.Partial("JobIndicatorList")

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

my problem is the new jquery tabcontrol(the second one) doesn't have actual behavior.

[this is output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Urv.jpg)

can anybody help me.
thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What do you mean by "doesn't work correctly"? Can you please be a little bit more specific (e.g. expected vs. actual behavior)? This makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: tank's @QueryLars. i edit the post